# IE8: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method (Line 1 Char 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple jquery code that work's fine, but not in IE8.

I have a button with `onclick="unlock();"`.
The `unlock()` function is in external file named `js/unlock.js`.

In the IE8 debugger tool it marks all of the function and write this error:

```
Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method (Line 1 Char 1)
```

The website is not writen in English, but please check this out. The `unlock` button looks like this: [image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/4135d0e39d2966938cd7154943ad900c.png))</sub>

Link to the website: http://www.nitrobit.net/view/RDIWVmLAJ
BTW: You need to write something in the input next to the button.

What is wrong?

The JS code: (unlock.js):

```
unlock = function() {
    var password = $("input[name='password']").val();
    if($.trim(password).length != 0) {
        locked_div = $("#locked_div").html();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/unlock.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { password: password, file: $("input[name='fileId']").val(), keep: ($("input[name='keep']").is(':checked')) ? 'true' : 'false' },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#locked_div").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.indexOf(0) == 0) {
                    data = data.slice(1);
                    $("#locked_div").html(locked_div);
                    $("#error").html(data);
                } else {
                    $("#locked_content").slideUp(); 
                    $("#prem_message").slideUp(function() {
                        $("#dl_section").html(data);
                        $("#download").fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks, and sorry for my English

Comment: Always include the relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link. In particular, we'd have to see where and how `unlock` is defined. (If it's defined within a scoping function, for instance, then it's not a global and isn't available from an `onclick="..."`-style handler.)

Comment: @insertusernamehere that would *definitely* be the problem.

Comment: @insertusernamehere there is `<base href="http://www.nitrobit.net/" />`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I updated the question and puted the code

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yes. the error is like I said `Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method (Line 1 Char 1)` And there are no other errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing your code in Internet Explorer 8 I get a slightly different position of the error:

> unlock.js, line 4, char 9

It's this line:

```
locked_div = $("#locked_div").html();
```

When looking for [IE8 and `.html()` on Google](https://www.google.com/#q=ie8+jquery+.html%28%29) you'll find lots of cases, where the `.html()`-method fails in [reading](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-html-bug-in-ajax-success-function-with-ie8) or writing. You also use an outdated version of jQuery (1.7).

I would suggest:

- update to jQuery 1.10.x
- if the problem persists, try to use plain JavaScript functionality instead
- or alternatively: clone the node instead of reading it's content

Comment: What's the meaning of "clone the node " ?

Comment: If I got yor right, you're trying to store the node value for later. You could also [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) (duplicate) the whole node and then replace it. Or you could grab all [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and replace the content later on. Both are alternatives to not use `html()`.

Comment: Thanks!!! I removed this variable and replaced it with something else, and now it works! Thank You